# ¿Diferencias entre .NET Core y .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

**A nivel de programación** ¿Hay grandes diferencias entre estos dos?, ¿Si aprendo uno, sé el otro? Todo lo que gusten aportar en su experiencia.

Comment: Google te dara la respuesta

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: 4 Cosas: 1. Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Esto es StackOverflow, no un grupo de fb, hay una estructura de preguntas y una estructura de respuestas. 2. `¿Hay grandes diferencias entre estos dos?` Sí. 3. `¿Si aprendo uno, sé el otro?` Prácticamente sí. 4. `Todo lo que gusten aportar en su experiencia.` Lee el recorrido del sitio, este lugar NO es para opiniones, un lugar ideal es la sala de chat que hay en https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol podrás acceder cuando tengas al menos unos 20-25 puntos. Saludos :D

Comment: **.NET Framework** solo funciona en Windows. **.NET Core** es multiplataforma.